# Protobuf: how to rewrite a file

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers

I'm using Protobuf3 as a file format.  The PB API works great for serialization and deserialization.  However I now want do a roundtrip: write a file, read it back, modify one field and rewrite the file back to storage.

In more detail: when creating a PB object, one first instantiates a `Builder` object, sets the field values in the object, and then Builds the binary object.  However, after writing and reading back the binary object, how does one modify a field?  One has to use a Builder object to generate the binary, but does one have to copy all the existing fields back into the Builder?  Or does the Builder automatically populate itself from the binary form?

Ideally, I could load the binary, create a new builder, set the field that I wanted and expect both the original and new data to be merged together.

What is best practice?

Comment: the API may be different between platforms and languages; can you specify exactly what you're using? is this the google implementation on Java, for example?

Comment: Both Java and Python.

Comment: And Yes, we are using the Google ProtoBuf implementation.  Its a quite an impressive tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deserialise you end up with an object that has fields set. You can modify these fields any which way you like. You can then serialise that object and write the new byte stream to a file.

You do not need to make a copy of the deserialised object to do this (however GPB implementations generally have a copy constructor if you wish to make a copy).

What you cannot do is edit the file in place; you have to completely rewrite the file. You have no sensible way of knowing what part of the byte stream has changed. It may have become longer, shorter, and the content itself will be different in any case (because you’ve changed fields in the object).

Comment: slight caveat: it *is* possible to make certain changes without rewriting - as long as you're editing the *root message*, and are either appending new sub-messages to `repeated`/`map` etc, or are updating the value of primitives - in *those cases* you can use the append===merge semantic of protobuf

Comment: @MarcGravell, absolutely yes, but I thought I’d leave that to later!

Comment: Great.  I was planning on full binary write after updating the fields.  So no problem there.  Thanks!

Comment: I assume that I still need to create a new `builder` object for each object and that the `builder` itself will be fully populated?

Comment: @Hephaestus, you mean write a number of different builder objects to the same file? You can have just one object; you can populate fields, serialise and write, change the fields, serialise and write, and so on. There's no special need to create a fresh object every time.

Comment: @bazza: (I can't find a way to neatly insert code here)  Here is a sample from Java.  
  mBuilder = ProtoClass.Object.newBuilder(); 
        mBuilder.setPacketType     ("foo");  
        mBuilder.setProtocolRev    ("bar");

Comment: I understand that a file can have a single root GPB object (top-level-object).  However, in our case we are using the 'repeated' type to build arrays of objects--within the top-level-object.  So for each object, I will need to access its builder, in order to set values in the fields.  The question is, will the "newBuilder()" be populated with the pre-existing data from the original serialized data that I read from the file.

Comment: @Hephaestus, Lets see if I've got this right. You have a single object type "Root" that has a repeated field of type "Builder", with the Root object (containing a number of Builder objects) serialised and stored in a file. I would say that you should deserialise the Root object from the file, and then you'd end up with a Root object in memory containing an array of Builder objects. I'm not sure that you can partially de-serialise the file one Builder at a time (I suspect Marc Gravell might have something to say about that!).

Comment: @Hephaestus, if you're populating a new Root object, you'd call its constructor, set the repeated Builders field to a new RepeatedField<Builder>, and then start adding new Builder objects to that.

Comment: If you did want to load Builders from a file one at a time, then they would have to have been individually serialised and written to that file. The problem comes if the resultant number of bytes per serialised build is not constant. You'd either have to have some kind of length indicator written separately (so that you know how many bytes to read for the next Builder), or some kind of specific pattern of bytes to act as a separator between individual Builder object's seriliased bytes.

Comment: One of the features of the GPB wire format is that it contains no demarkation between messages; you have to add these yourself. Fine if you're using something like ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ (these do this for you), not fine if you're using a socket or file (there's no message separator; they're just byte streams). Other serialisation technologies like ASN.1 do have the ability to determine the end of one message and the start of another.

Comment: @Bazza.  Thank you for the detailed response.  The "Builder" is a Google ProtoBuf defined object, not mine.  See the docs: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#builders.  They use these "Builders" as part of the design pattern for generating the wire format.  So, the builders aren't mine.  However, we have to use them to generate the final binary wire format.

Comment: In our case, we are happy to use a full binary read/write of the entire PB object--no need for a partial reads or writes.  Memory is cheap and the files are not overly large.